# How to permanently delete a 37signals ID

Tags: account-management, basecamp

I know how to delete/cancel individual Highrise or Basecamp accounts, but I’m interested in deleting the *global* 37signals ID (the one used for the [Launchpad](https://launchpad.37signals.com/signin)) and so far I haven’t found a way to do it.

So, how can I completely delete a 37signals ID?

Comment: Alex, this is a bit of conjecture, but deleting a global 37Signals ID might require a special Support request. You can of course "disable" a user by removing them from all 37Signals accounts (Basecamp, Highrise, etc.).

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: If you mean how to contact Support to request them to permanently delete an ID, then I think you could do this here: https://help.37signals.com/bcx/tickets/new. Provide them the user's name and email, let them know you'd like the user's global Launchpad ID to be deleted; and see what they say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding, deleting a global 37Signals user ID requires a special Support request.

There are various ways to contact 37Signals Support ... assuming you're a Basecamp account owner, you can go here: https://help.37signals.com/bcx/tickets/new.  Provide them the user's name and email; and let them know you'd like the user's global Launchpad ID to be deleted.

(Alternatively, you could effectively "disable" the user by simply removing them from all 37Signals accounts [Basecamp, Highrise, etc.]).